# Increasing concave function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a concave function with $f(1)=\sup_{t\in[0,1]} f(t)$. Then $f$ is non-decreasing in $[0,1]$. Does someone know how to prove this?

Comment: Assume $f$ were not non-decreasing. Then there are $0 \leqslant x < y \leqslant 1$ with $f(x) > f(y)$. Deduce $f(1) \leqslant f(y)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there exist $x,y\in [0,1]$ with $x<y$ s.t. $f(x)>f(y)$. Then there exists $t\in (0,1)$ with $y = (1-t)x+t\cdot 1$ (because $y$ is in between $x$ and $1$). It follows that

$f(y) = f((1-t)x+t) \geq (1-t)f(x)+tf(1) > (1-t)f(y)+tf(1)$.

Hence $f(y) > f(1)$ (by subtracting $(1-t)f(y)$ and then dividing by $t$).

Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ is concave if and only if $$\Delta:\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2: a<b\}\to \mathbb{R}\\\Delta(a,b)={f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}$$
is a weakly-decreasing (i.e. non-increasing) function in both $a$ and $b$ (while keeping the other one fixed).

Now, suppose there were $0\leq a\lt b\leq 1$ such that $f(b)-f(a)<0$. Then, $\Delta(a,b)<0$

But then, $${f(1)-f(a)\over 1}\le{f(1)-f(a)\over 1-a}=\Delta(a,1)\leq \Delta(a,b)<0$$

But this means $f(a)>f(1)=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}f(t)$. Absurd, because $a\in[0,1]$